# Return DateTime from database in JSON format using javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, json

I am getting a dateTime back from the stored procedure getDateTime.  The format I recieve it back in is very weird (shown below)

This is how it looks (incorrect return)

```
{"dateTime":"Wed Apr 01 2015 04:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)","Thu Apr 02 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"}]}
```

This is what I want it to return

```
{"dateTime":["2015-04-01T04:00:00Z","2015-04-02T12:00:00Z"]}
```

Here is the code that get the dateTime

```
mssql.query("EXEC getDateTime ?", [meetingID],  
        {
            success: function(results) {
                var length = results.length;
                var dateTime = results[0].meetingDateTime; //this part!!!!
                for (var x= 1; x < length; x++) {
                    dateTime =  dateTime + results[x].meetingDateTime
                }
        }
```

Comment: What database engine are you using that returns this date format? Can you change the stored procedure?

Comment: using microsoft azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) method

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toJSON();
```

More [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tojson.asp)

Comment: Worked, thanks.  DId 
var dateTime = results[0].meetingDateTime;
var d = new Date(dateTime);
var n = d.toJSON();

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is convert a date to the ISO 8601 format.

In oracle use

```
TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"')
```

In MSSQL user

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, date_column, 126)
```

javascript will happily gulp this value into a date object

Also, if you are putting this value into a POCO, POJO then change that type to a string so as not to alter the format

In your loop

Comment: I suspect it is MS SQL server, not Oracle. Check the OP's code: `mssql.query`